# How to prevent user from turning a car around against traffic in 3D game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, stage3d

I'm making a 3D game in flash using Flare3D and I have a track that consists of long straight sections and short curving sections of track. The player is free to steer their car, but I need to be able to prevent them from making a U-turn and driving backwards down the track.

Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Comment: the track is a non-repeating urban environment created in 3D studio max. The player races from one end to the other, not laps.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know AS3 syntax, but the general idea would be to define the direction of travel for each segment (at least the straight segments) and an acceptable deviance.  Then if the player's direction falls outside the deviance then you turn them back on course or make them crash or whatever you want.

Example:

straight track segment is 30-degrees.  Deviance is +-20.  User's direction can be anywhere from 10 to 50 degrees before you start kickin their butt.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it, is to segment the track, and for each segment of the track have a direction that it faces (just as boo said)  So if the track is facing north, and that is 0/360, then the segments in the track at that point would be 0.  After they make the first turn, lets say that is a 90 to the right, then the track at that point would have a value of 90.

Once you have enough segments, and they all have the directions, then what you can do is look ahead.  So if they are on segment 10, look at segment 11, and use that segments value as the limitation that boo pointed to (+/- 20 degrees).  That might solve any issues you have while they are in the turns, to allow them to steer thru the turns, but still be able to crash.

This assumes your tracking the segment they are currently in, and that there is just one segment ahead.  You might have to adopt it, if the track has choices.

Also,

If they try to turn the car slowly around, I would agree with Boo. Check the angle of the car on the road, and only allow so much of a change, maybe add a sound that enforces that they have turned the wheel as far as it is going to go so they understand why it is not turning any more.

IF they are moving fast when they try it, I would add a crash animation, and then reset their car back on track.  The user would learn to avoid facing the wrong way, as it crashes when you do.

Comment: I agree with the principle of what you and @Boo say: Find out how far they should be able to turn and make sure they don't turn farther. But I'm not at all clear how to go about doing that. The track does not have regular segments. I need a method that polls the world somehow, possibly using normals or collision data to derive an angle.

Comment: I would assume that you have your car in world coordinates, and you have a vector representing car direction.  That vector needs to be converted to world coordinates also.  With those to parts, you should be able to determine the direction the car is heading at any time.  You would also have to make a map of the road, with segments (maybe simplified to 2d unless the road overlaps).  With that, you need to figure out which segment your in.  Thats how it would work.  I dont think there is any simple method that would react to the track to determine direction.